# Django ORM: Dynamically determine another table name according one field value

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I hit one problem when generate orm query upon there tables.

I have models here:

```
class Task(models.Model):

    deliver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, related_name='task')
    tasktype = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True)  
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    delivertime = models.DateTimeField(default=now,db_index=True)
    deadlinetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,db_index=True)
    relatedresourceid = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)  
    suggestspendtime = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 
    subjectid = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)

class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
```

So, here I wanna query from Task model, what's more, for every Task object in queryset:

I wanna get a value with key "name" from Lesson or Exam model, i.e for every Task object, if tasktype is 1, then get name value from Lesson model (where `pk==relatedresourceid`), if tasktype is 2 , then take it from Exam model.

I use Django1.8 and Mysql 5.6

Anyone know how to query using ORM?

Thanks.

Comment: Does each task belongs either to a Lesson or an Exam? In the real-life problem you are trying to solve i mean.

Comment: Yes, each task belongs either to a Lesson or an Exam. if tasktype is 1 , it's to Lesson, 2 is for Exam. And get Lesson or Exam object by relatedresourceid

Comment: Then you should model the situation in another way, take my response below

Comment: Yeah, I know we can use ForeignKey or other constraint, however, with some special reason, we didn't use.  Maybe we can do this with raw sql, but I don't wanna due to database engine tranfer later. Actually, I don't know how to write the raw sql either ... Haha

Comment: I know the `tasktype` tells the table you need to look at, but then, which `name` _of all_ in the Exam/Lesson tables you have to take?

Comment: by relatedresourceid, like foreigh key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should model the situation in another way:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    deliver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=False, related_name='task')
    tasktype = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True)  
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    delivertime = models.DateTimeField(default=now,db_index=True)
    deadlinetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,db_index=True)
    relatedresourceid = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)  
    suggestspendtime = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 
    subjectid = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, related_name='lessons') 

class Exam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, related_name='exams')
```

That way, you can easily have the name of the Lesson or Exam the Task belongs to `<a task>.lessons` or `<a task>.exams`

For your current approach, you can take all names this way:

```
[{'task_id':task.pk, 'name': Lesson.objects.get(pk=task.relatedresourceid).name if task.tasktype==1 else Exam.objects.get(pk=task.relatedresourceid).name} for task in Task.objects.all()]
```

This will give you a list like: `[{'task_id':1, 'name': <Lesson or Exam name 1>}, {'task_id':2, 'name': <Lesson or Exam name 2>}, ..., {'task_id':N, 'name': <Lesson or Exam name N>}]`

Comment: Cannot use foreighkey or manytomanyfield, besides relatedresourceid we also need tasktype to address Lesson or Exam object.

Comment: Sorry, buddy, I need leave for a while, will respond you when back. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my question more detailed. I don't wanna traverse the queryset again, if so, I can get the result without any related field. What I am asking is could we get the result from one ORM query string?

Comment: This won't be possible with your current models structure, since you don't have relations between them.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I will dig into this later but accept your answer now. Thx.